# Switch not toggling between light and dark modes with ThemeProvider

Tags: flutter, dart

Basically the title. I apply the functions to the CupertinoSwitch values but it doesn't toggle. To make sure of it, if I hardcode the value to true, the switch turns green, so I guess it's something in the onChanged. Am I toggling it wrong inside the theme_provider?

theme_provider.dart

```
import 'package:chat_app/themes/dark_mode.dart';
import 'package:chat_app/themes/light_mode.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final ThemeData _themeData = lightMode;

  ThemeData get getTheme => _themeData;

  bool get isDarkMode => _themeData == darkMode;

  set themeData(ThemeData themeData) {
    themeData = themeData;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void toggleTheme() {
    themeData = isDarkMode ? lightMode : darkMode;
  }
}
```

settings.dart

```
import 'package:chat_app/themes/theme_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Settings"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        foregroundColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        ),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            const Text("Dark Mode"),
            CupertinoSwitch(
              value: Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).isDarkMode,
              onChanged: (value) =>
                  Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false)
                      .toggleTheme(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CupertinoSwitch` is taking the value of `isDarkMode`, which is a getter that checks if `_themeData` is equal to `darkMode`. But in the `themeData` setter, you're doing `themeData = themeData`, and both `themeData` here refer to the parameter (which [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the `themeData` property of the class). Calling the actual `themeData` setter would be wrong too, because it will keep call itself indefinitely. What you have to do is to set `_themeData` instead.

```
set themeData(ThemeData themeData) {
  _themeData = themeData;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

Comment: oh right! How silly of me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add  notifyListeners() statement after this line :
themeData = isDarkMode ? lightMode : darkMode;

and make sure that you added a ThemeProvider object in a changenotifierprovider wrapped around the materialapp